# Display nested objects using w3-repeat of w3.js library

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to display an array of objects with nested array of objects using the tag `w3-repeat` of the library w3.js. I know that it's not a main used library, but i'm new to this stuff and i liked the w3.css style for css styling (simple and easy-to-learn) and so i'm trying w3.js for the javascript side.
I'm trying to make a table starting with an object like this:

```
var myObject = {
    "deliveries" : [
        {
        "state" : "inside",
        "arrive" : "15/09/17 - 15:00",
        "courier" : "courier 1",
        "cli-cust" : [
            {
            "type" : "client",
            "name" : "cli. name",
            "goods" : [
                {"material" : "pasta",
                "qt" : "200"},
                {"material" : "bread",
                 "qt" : "300"},
                {"material" : "oil",
                 "qt" : "1000"}
                ]
            },
            {
            "type" : "customer",
            "name" : "name of customer",
            "goods" : [
                {"material" : "water",
                "qt" : "100"},
                {"material" : "wine",
                 "qt" : "3000"},
                {"material" : "prosecco",
                 "qt" : "2000"}
                ]
            }
        ]
        },
        {
        "state" : "outside",
        "arrive" : "15/09/17 - 16:00",
        "courier" : "courier 2",
        "cli-cust" : [
            {
            "type" : "client",
            "name" : "name of client 2",
            "goods" : [
                {"material" : "notebook",
                "qt" : "10"},
                {"material" : "keyboard",
                 "qt" : "30"}
                ]
            }
        ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Basically the result should be a table like this:
[image: table]
Now, i tryed the tag `w3-repeat` but seems to work for the first level of array objects (state, arrive, courier), but not for the others:
This works fine:

```
<tr w3-repeat="deliveries">
<td>{{state}}</td>
<td>{{arrive}}</td>
<td>{{courier}}</td>
```

but for the second level object I have tryed to use something like

```
<ul w3-repeat="cli-cust">
<li>{{type}}</li>
<li>{{name}}</li>
</ul>
```

and for the third level something similar

```
<ul w3-repeat="goods">
<li>{{material}}</li>
<li>{{qt}}</li>
</ul>
```

but does not work: gives `{{type}}`, `{{name}}`, `{{material}}`, `{{qt}}` as text in the output, seems that can't use the nested objects for loop the array. I obtain the same result using `w3-repeat="deliveries.cli-cust"` and `w3-repeat="deliveries.goods"` instead of `w3-repeat="cli-cust"` and `w3-repeat="goods"`.

Am i missing something or the library can't support this feature?

**Edit 24/09/17: The library can't resolve nested objects, so there is no way for achieve the request.**

Thanks
Ettore

Comment: try to repeat `deliveries.cli-cust` and `deliveries.cli-cust.goods` ?

Comment: tryed but same result, edited the question, thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

The `w3.displayObject(id,model)` cannot resolve a nested model.

For example you could have two w3-repeats.

```
<div id='id01'>
    <table>
        <tr w3-repeat="deliveries">
            <td>{{state}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <ul w3-repeat="customers">
        <li>{{type}}</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

This could be handled by a model with "deliveries" and "customers" properties.

```
<script>
    var model = {
        deliveries: [
            { state: "inside" },
            { state: "outside" }
        ],
        customers: [
            { type: "client" },
            { type: "customer" }
        ]
    }
    w3.displayObject('id01', model);
</script>
```

Notice the `w3.displayObject()` function uses the same model for all elements with the w3-repeat attribute.

Even if the w3-repeat elements are nested the same model is used and the customers are repeated inside of each delivery.

```
<div id='id02'>
    <table>
        <tr w3-repeat="deliveries">
            <td>{{state}}</td>
            <td>
                <ul w3-repeat="customers">
                    <li>{{type}}</li>
                </ul>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>

<script>
    w3.displayObject('ido2', model)
</script>

  <script>w3.displayObject('ido2',model)</script.
```

If the code of `w3.displayObject()` function were hacked it would require some way of indicating how to navigate the nested model.  Let's say it looked like this:

```
<ul w3-repeat='deliveries[$i].customers'>
```

That's not an easy hack.

Comment: In fact i realized that the function can't resolve nested objects, so no way for do what i need with the w3.js library. I made my own functions for resolve the problem. Anyway thanks for the reply.