# Difficulty reading information in w3.js

Tags: javascript, w3.js

in w3.js

```
    {
"customers":[
{"CustomerName" : "Alfreds Futterkiste","City" : "Berlin","Country" : "Germany"},
{"CustomerName" : "Berglunds snabbköp","City" : "Luleå","Country" : "Sweden"},
]}


<select id="id01">
  <option w3-repeat="customers">{{CustomerName}}</option>
</select>



<script>
w3.getHttpObject("customers.js", myFunction);

function myFunction(myObject) {
  w3.displayObject("id01", myObject);
}
</script>
```

but my object not any name like(customers)  and is:

```
[{"id":12,"name":"hamwrew"},{"id":13,"name":"mamad2"}]
```

how to show my object? in html or jsp page

Comment: In `w3.displayObject` you can add your objects name `{customers: myObject}` and then in the template instead of referencing `CustomerName`, you will just reference `name` (since that is the property in each object in your array).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have an object but an array so first create an object from your array:

```
var dataArray = [{"id":12,"name":"hamwrew"},{"id":13,"name":"mamad2"}];
var nameList = { names: dataArray };
```

so:

```
    <select id="id01">   
      <option w3-repeat="names" value={{id}}>{{name}}</option>
    </select>

    <script>
      w3.getHttpObject("customers.js", myFunction);

      function myFunction(myArray) {   
        var nameList = { names: myArray};   
        w3.displayObject("id01", nameList);
      }
   </script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much .it's true if dataArray  is                ```[{"id":12,"name":"hamwrew","countries":[{"id":5,"name":"iran","capital":"ir"},{"id":6,"name":"usa","capital":"us"}]},{"id":13,"name":"mamad2","countries":[]}]```                 how to show country.name

Comment: So you want 2 <select>, first with choice of user and the second the choice of the user country ?

Comment: yes for example                                                                                                ```<table id="id01">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Country Name</th>
    </tr>

    <tr w3-repeat="names">
        <td>{{name}}</td>
        <td>{{id}}</td>
        <td>{{countries..name}}</td>

    </tr>
</table>```

Comment: Like it is says here, w3.js can't do repeat nested object. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45777819/display-nested-objects-using-w3-repeat-of-w3-js-library

Comment: There is a 'native' way to do this with for loop or array map base on this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement

Comment: I did not notice this document . I just want to show countries.name next to the Id and name

Comment: Have a look a this. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model/Traversing_an_HTML_table_with_JavaScript_and_DOM_Interfaces. In your case, you need a loop inside thé first one. First loop for names, inside this loop, loop for countries.